# How to fix a react-hooks/exhaustive-deps linting error with no dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a linting error (`react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`) that I am currently disabling on two lines. I understand how the code is breaking the rule, but I do not understand why this rule applies to this situation.

I want an effect to only run for cleanUp purposes when the component unmounts. I have a function, `clearMessages`, which is inherited from props which reset the state of a reducer back to its empty default state. It works fine when I run my project locally, but when I run the build react-scripts throws the above linting error and the build fails.

Here is a short snippet showing the effect that causes the problem.

```
const Search = ({ clearMessages }) => {

useEffect(() => () => clearMessages(), [])

...
...

}
```

This is the error message that react-scripts build throws.

> Line 25:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:
>   'clearMessages'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If
>   'clearMessages' changes too often, find the parent component that
>   defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback 
>   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I would not expect `clearMessages` to change, so I am not sure why it is important that I provide it as a dependency. I do not want the effect to the only run when the value of `clearMessages` changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix missing dependency in React Hook useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-do-i-fix-missing-dependency-in-react-hook-useeffect/55854902#55854902)

Answer (score 3):

Along with the above answer, I found this documentation to be very helpful for reorganizing my useEffect when there is a functional dependency:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

If `clearMessages` does not change, it is equivalent to an empty dependency array - `[]`.

Either way, because "I **would not expect** `clearMessages` to change" you should use it in the dep array like the linter suggests.

```js
const Search = ({ clearMessages }) => {

// Equivalent to an empty dependency array !if! clearMessages never change.
useEffect(() => () => clearMessages(), [clearMessages])
```

There are two phases to `useEffect` mentioned above:

1. `useEffect` will run when `clearMessages` changes (if it doesn't it will run only on the component mount).
2. By specifying a return callback, the callback will run on component unmount.

> [Quote from docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1): **When exactly does React clean up an effect?** React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

When I read the docs for hooks, it said that if you provide a dependency, it will only call the function being returned in useEffect when that dependency changes. Would this still be called when the component unmounts even though clearMessages is still the same function?